# Ordering a rank of championships in C

Tags: c

I'd like to know how to build a program in C that can read and give the results of championships.
In this program we will get from the user: how many championships, the name of the championship, how many teams are in the championship (then the user write the names of the teams), the number of games in the championship, and then the result of the games in this format, as example:

Mexico#3@3#Spain

Poland#2@0#France

...

And then we will get all these infos and display the rank of it, something like this:

1. Poland, 3 points, 1 game, 1 wins, 0 draws, 0 losses, 2 goals dif, 2 goals made and 2 goals suffered
2. Mexico, 1 point, 1 game, 0 wins, 1 draws, 0 losses, 0 goals dif, ...

(This comes in an order, so if you have more points (victory = 3, draw = 1, defeat = 0) you will be in the top of the rank, if you have more draws, goals difference etc)

So, here's my question:

I tried to do this program several times without struct and I failed on it because I had no clue how to order it. (I know how to order normal integer arrays, but in this case I don't know how to order it because, for example, if I order to higher every array there, it doesn't mean that the team which played more games did more points, ie, this is not necessarily true, so if I order to higher if a team played more and this team made less points, this program will be wrong; if I order by the number of points, not necessarily the team that did more points has the highest number of games played, maybe someone played more times and had less points and, in this case, I'd print the team with most points with more games than it actually played, ie, it's wrong).

Then I tried using an array of structs and I also failed on it, because I don't know how I am supposed to order things that are not in an array. Even if I put the things that are inside the structs (number of victories, goals_made, goals_suffered...) in an outside array, I won't know what integer inside the array belongs to what team, making it not possible to order the rank.

Does someone know how could I make this kind of program? If I really should use an array of structs? If yes, how could I do it and if not, how could I do it.

Note that this is some kind of thing that I need to do so please do not post any giant code here in the answer, just lead me to what I must do to achieve it. (Of course if the code is part of the explaining on how I can do it I'd be pleasured to read).

Here is what I got so far in my main:

```
typedef struct teams{
    int victories, defeats, draws, goals_made, goals_suffered, games, points;
    char name[30];
}TEAMS;


int ret, ret2, cont, cont2;
char caractere, caractere2;
char line[30], line2[30];
int i, j, k, l = 0, h = 0, n, t = 0, x = 30;  //t = number of teams     n = number of championships
char championship[100];
unsigned int g; //g = number of games already played in the championship
char useless;
int value1, value2, aux;

TEAMS zoera[30];

scanf("%d", &n);
fflush(stdin);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%[^\n]", championship);
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(j = 0; j < t; j++){
        scanf("%s", zoera[j].name);
    }
    for(aux = 0; aux < t; aux++){
        zoera[aux].victories = 0;
        zoera[aux].defeats = 0;
        zoera[aux].draws = 0;
        zoera[aux].goals_made = 0;
        zoera[aux].goals_suffered = 0;
        zoera[aux].games = 0;
        zoera[aux].points = 0;
    }

    scanf("%u", &g);
    for(k = 0; k < g; k++){
        //scanf("%s", azedo2[k]);
        do{
           caractere = getchar();
           line[l] = caractere;
           l++;
        }while(caractere != '#');
        for(cont = 0; cont < t; cont++){
            ret = strcmp(line, zoera[cont].name);
            if(ret == 0){
               scanf("%c", &useless);
               scanf("%d", &value1);
               scanf("%c", &useless);
               scanf("%d", &value2);
               do{
                  caractere2 = getchar();
                  line2[h] = caractere2;
                  h++;
               }while(caractere2 != '\n');
                for(cont2 = 0; cont2 < t; cont2++){
                    ret2 = strcmp(line2, zoera[cont2].name);
                    if(ret2 == 0){
                        zoera[cont].games += 1;
                        zoera[cont2].games += 1;
                        zoera[cont].goals_made += value1;
                        zoera[cont2].goals_made += value2;
                        zoera[cont].goals_suffered += value2;
                        zoera[cont2].goals_suffered += value1;
                        if(value1 > value2){
                            zoera[cont].points += 3;
                            zoera[cont].victories += 1;
                            zoera[cont2].defeats += 1;
                        }
                        if(value1 == value2){
                            zoera[cont].points += 1;
                            zoera[cont2].points += 1;
                            zoera[cont].draws += 1;
                            zoera[cont2].draws += 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            zoera[cont2].points += 3;
                            zoera[cont2].victories += 1;
                            zoera[cont].defeats += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to decide what parameter you need to order it by first. Is it total no of points, or total no of games played, or average points per game. The order will be different depending on the parameter. The you can go about calculating that parameter (sum/average etc) and sorting by that.

Comment: Ok but, let's suppose that Poland did 3 games, got 5 points and did 6 goals.
Then Spain did 2 games, got 6 points and did 4 goals.
Then I will put Spain at the top because it has more points, but how am I supposed to put that Spain played 2 games and not 3 games?

Comment: The order will be determined by the problem you are trying to solve. From what i see in the problem description "so if you have more points (victory = 3, draw = 1, defeat = 0) you will be in the top of the rank,.." So first you have to order it by the points. Then there will be some other parameter if points are equal (draws? goal difference? etc)

Comment: Yes, for example, if the number of points are equal, the most number of victories will define the highest.
If numbers of victories are the same, difference of goals will define the highest, then most goals made and less games played.

Answer (score 0):

You should first build a comparison function which can tell you whether a team has a higher ranking than the other. This will have all the logic of the problem, e.g. points, draws etc.

```
int compare (TEAM *a, TEAM *b)
{
   if (a-> points != b -> points)
   {
      return ((a-> points) - (b-> points));
   }
   else if (a-> draws != b-> draws)
   {
      return ((a-> draws) - (b-> draws));
   }
   // any other logic that determines rank (games played etc)

   return 0;
}
```

Then you can use this function in a bubble sort or any other sorting algorithm.

```
int main(void)
{
   // Code to read the TEAMS from file.
   // total_teams should have the total no of teams read from file.

   for (i=0; i< total_teams -1; i++) 
   {
      for (j=0; j< total_teams -1; j++)
      {
         if ((compare(&zoera[j], &zoera[j+1]) > 0) 
         {
            // swap zoera[j] and zoera[j+1]
            temp_team = zoera[j];
            zoera[j] = zoera[j+1];
            zoera[j+1] = temp_team;
         }
      }
   }

   // Code to print the teams, if required.
}
```